# URL Blocking Bots

Tags: ssl, bots, robots.txt, lets-encrypt

I have a client who I am trying to setup an SSL certificate for via SSL for Free, like I have done 100 times before.

I created the file structure under `public_html`:

- `.well-known` > `pki-validation` > `<uploaded verification file>`

I then tried to download the certificate and got the following failure message:

> Warning: Your verification URL is not returning the correct contents
> to our verification servers. The URL looks like it is blocking bots
> and which inadvertently blocks our servers from receiving the correct
> content. Contact your host, a professional developer or admin for
> further help with fixing it.

I assumed this was due to the `robots.txt` file, had a look and it included the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

So I changed it to temporarily allow all bots using:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow:
```

I then retried the process, uploading the new verification file, but still, I get the same warning message about the URL blocking the bots. Has anyone come across this before and know how to fix it?

I've also tried verification via a DNS .txt record and via FTP, both returning the same failure notices.

Hosting is through GoDaddy and they're using Linux cPanel. The website is made through WordPress.

Typing in `example.com/robots.txt` returns the correct `robots.txt` file.

Thank you for all and any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've now fixed this issue. It was indeed to do with the `robots.txt` file as I had initially thought. The reason it didn't initially work is the site was still cached with the old file, which was blocking bots throughout the site.

I added some code to my `.htaccess` file to force re-validation of the cache:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

After doing this and with my new `robots.txt` file, I was able to install the new SSL certificate to the website which is now working! I hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

Just remember to remove the above code afterwards, as it will temporarily stop your site from caching.

Comment: Works like a charm! You just saved me a lot of thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue within the SSL For Free portal. After clicking on renew within the "certificates" link, I hit the "regenerate account" link. Then went through the usual steps to renew and it worked.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your answer, but this isn't for a renewal, but an entirely new setup.